# Bash's Process Substitution "<(command)" equivalent in fish shell

Tags: fish

In bash, I usually do `grep -f <(command) ...` (I pick grep just for example) to mimic a file input.

What is the equivalent in fish shell? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<()` and `>()` constructs are known as "[process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)". I don't use `fish`, but according to [its documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html), it doesn't directly support this:

> Subshells, command substitution and process substitution are strongly related. fish only supports command substitution, the others can be achieved either using a block or the psub shellscript function.

Indeed, [`psub` seems to be what you want](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/psub.html):

```
## bash
$ seq 10 | grep -f <(seq 4 5)
4
5

## fish
~> seq 10 | grep -f (seq 4 5 | psub)
4
5
```

Comment: fish currently has no equivalent to `>()` output process substitution.

Comment: Also note that `fish`'s `psub` uses a temporary file, so it's closer to `zsh`'s `=(...)` form of process substitution than `<(...)`. It has a `psub --fifo`, but is [severely broken](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1040) and cannot really be fixed (and still waits for the psub'ed command to finish for the `(...)` to expand which means it's still really not an IPC mechanism like ksh/bash/zsh's `<(...)`).

Comment: Here, one can use `command | grep -f - ...` in any  shell.

Comment: Right, the value of process substitution is when you need to pass multiple streams of content to a process. E.g. `diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`