# fish 'Invalid redirection target' error

Tags: shell, fish

This command works well in Bash and Zsh:

```
expac -H M "%011m\t%-20n\t%10d" $(comm -23 <(pacman -Qqen | sort) <({ pacman -Qqg xorg; expac -l '\n' '%E' base; } | sort -u)) | sort -n
```

But in Fish, it leads to this error:

```
fish: Invalid redirection target: 
comm -23 <(pacman -Qqen | sort) <({ pacman -Qqg xorg; expac -l '\n' '%E' base; } | sort -u)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
in command substitution
fish: Unknown error while evaluating command substitution
expac -H M "%011m\t%-20n\t%10d" $(comm -23 <(pacman -Qqen | sort) <({ pacman -Qqg xorg; expac -l '\n' '%E' base; } | sort -u)) | sort -n
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

What is this error? and how can I fix the command to work in Fish?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash's Process Substitution "<(command)" equivalent in fish shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608633/bashs-process-substitution-command-equivalent-in-fish-shell)

Comment: Thanks, yes, to a good extent, but partially. Should I answer that form question yes or no?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) and the description of a later error, I found my answer. two things in the command need to be changed to work correctly:

1. fish doesn't support <(), instead should use '| psub'.
2. fish doesn't support '{ ... }' for grouping commands, should use 'begin; ...; end'.

so the correct command would be:

```
expac -H M "%011m\t%-20n\t%10d" $(comm -23 (pacman -Qqen | sort | psub) (begin; pacman -Qqg xorg; expac -l '\n' '%E' base; end | sort -u | psub)) | sort -n
```